# Office.EnhancedLocation failing with error 2006 "Invalid Format Error" in Outlook Client

Tags: office-js, outlook-addin

OWA still works but the Windows Outlook client fails when trying to set the Enhanced Location.  Was working fine a few days ago.  May be tied to the rollout of WebView2.

```
export const AddOutlookLocationAsync = (evt: Office.EnhancedLocation, location: Office.LocationIdentifier) => {
      const who: string = "AddOutlookLocationAsync";
      return new Promise<string>((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
          const locs: Office.LocationIdentifier[] = [];
          locs.push(location);
          DebugLog(who, "Add location " + JSON.stringify(location));
          evt.addAsync(locs, null, (result: Office.AsyncResult<void>) => {
            if (result.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
              resolve();
            } else {
              reject();
            }
          });
        } catch (e) {
          DebugLog(who, "Catch " + JSON.stringify(e));
          reject(e);
        }
      });
    };
```

> location {id: "Blackburn Fishbowl", type: "room"}

> id: "Blackburn Fishbowl"
> type: "room"
> **proto**: Object

Response

result

> OSF.DDA.AsyncResult {value: undefined, status: "failed", error:
> OSF.DDA.Error} error: OSF.DDA.Error code: 2006 message: "The format of
> the specified data object is invalid." name: "Invalid Format Error"
> **proto**: Object status: "failed" value: undefined
> **proto**: Object

[image]

Comment: Could you share your Outlook and Windows build numbers please. Also, it's worth trying the enhancedLocation API in ScriptLab for outlook to confirm if you're able to reproduce the issue. You can install ScriptLab for Outlook from the AppStore. It's also worth trying your snippet without passing in null in evt.addAsync. The options parameter is optional.

Comment: It's happening on multiple Windows machines (one in the UK plus mine that I know of). Outlook is V2101 Build 13801.20360, 16.0.13801.20288 64-bit.       Edition Windows 10 Pro
Version 20H2
Installed on ‎11/‎28/‎2020
OS build 19042.867
Experience Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.551.0

Comment: I need to pass in Null because TypeScript errors the line without that parameter.  Type '(result: AsyncResult<void>) => void' has no properties in common with type 'AsyncContextOptions'.

Comment: Microsoft Store does not have anything called "Scriptlab".

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, there was a typo in the original comment, please try to search up "Script Lab" (2 words) instead. You should be able to search for Script Lab after clicking on the "Get Add-ins" button in the Outlook ribbon, and for reference here's a link to the add-in on the online App Store: https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/office/WA200001603?tab=Overview

It might also be worth trying to pass in "{}" instead of "null".

Comment: Switched to {}, no change in behavior. <br/>      ` evt.addAsync(locs, {}, (result: Office.AsyncResult<void>) => {
        if (result.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
          resolve();
        } else {
          DebugLogError(who, "Failure " + JSON.stringify(result));
          // Treat this as non-fatal and hope things work out in the Subscription process
          resolve();
        }
      });`

Comment: Script Lab aborts with the same message.  $("#run").click(run);

function run() {
  let locs: Office.LocationIdentifier[] = [];
  let loc1 = { id: "Blackburn Fishbowl", type: Office.MailboxEnums.LocationType.Room };
  locs.push(loc1);
  Office.context.mailbox.item.enhancedLocation.addAsync(locs, {}, (result: Office.AsyncResult<void>) => {
      if (result.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
        console.log("ok");
      } else {
        console.error(result.error);
      }
    });
}

Comment: One other note, just tested with Mac Outlook and no error.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code snippet you provided, when the location type is a Room, the id field needs to be the an Email address instead of a regular string.
Here's the documentation for reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.locationidentifier?view=outlook-js-preview

Comment: Ok.  Why does it work in OWA and Mac Outlook?